# How to extract text between <h1></h1> in Python?

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm stuck extracting text between `<h1>` and `</h1>`.

Please help me.

My code is:

```
import bs4
import re
import urllib2

url2='http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=ch_vn_mobile_filter_Top%20Brands_All#jumpTo=0|20'
htmlf = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlf)
#res=soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'product-unit'})
for res in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'fk-display-block'}):
    suburl='http://www.flipkart.com/'+res.get('href')
    subhtml = urllib2.urlopen(suburl)
    subhtml = subhtml.read()
    subhtml = re.sub(r'\s\s+','',subhtml)
    subsoup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(subhtml)
    res2=subsoup.find('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'})
    if res2:
        print res2
```

The output:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">Moto G</h1>
<h1 itemprop="name">Moto E</h1>
<h1 itemprop="name">Moto E</h1>
```

But I want this:

```
Moto G
Moto E
Moto E
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On any HTML tag, doing a `get_text()` gives the text associated with the tag. So, you just need to use [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) on res2. i.e.,

```
if res2:
    print res2.get_text()
```

**PS**: As a side note, I think this line `subhtml = re.sub(r'\s\s+','',subhtml)` in your code is an expensive operation. If all you are doing is getting rid of the excessive spaces, you could do that with:

```
if res2:
    print res2.get_text().strip()
```

Comment: You could also use `res2.text` instead of `res2.get_text()`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496332/differences-between-text-and-get-text).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 res2=subsoup.find('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'})
    if res2:
        print res2.text
```

add `res2.text` and it will do the trick.