# Differences between .text and .get_text()

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In `BeautifulSoup`, is there any difference between `.text` and `.get_text()`?

Which one should be preferred for getting element's text?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = "<div>text1 <span>text2</span><div>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> div = soup.div
>>> div.text
'text1 text2'
>>> div.get_text()
'text1 text2'
```

Comment: Basically you can use a custom separator using `get_text()`, and you should use it as `.text` is a private property and not even documented.

Comment: @Selcuk yeah, I am personally using `get_text()` all of the time mostly because it is explicitly documented, but I'm seeing a lot of bs4 users are using `.text` directly and got curious about the downsides of that. Thanks!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Hmm...then what's `div.string`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like [`.text` is just a property that calls `get_text`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L296).  Therefore, calling `get_text` without arguments is the same thing as `.text`.  However, `get_text` can also support various keyword arguments to change how it behaves (`separator`, `strip`, `types`).  If you need more control over the result, then you need the functional form.

Comment: About the link, I think it's [line 296](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L296)

Comment: Yep.  Probably moved around a bit since I created this post so many years ago.