# How to collect data from html with beautiful soup and put it a list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to collect data from html files and then put some into variable or list.
But i don't understand Beautiful Soup very much. especially how to navigate through structure.

Here what is the best way to get src url attribute ? :

```
<div id="headshot">
<img title="Photo of someone" alt="Photo of somenone" src="url/file.jpg">
</div>
```

Here how to navigate and put p class values in list ? :

```
                <p class="bioheading">value</p>
                <div class="biodata">value</div>
                <p class="bioheading">value</p>
                <p class="biodata">value</p>
                <p class="bioheading">value</p>
                <p class="biodata"><a href"http://url.com/month=01&amp;year=2018&amp;day=02">January 01, 1900</a> (117 years old)</p>
                <p class="bioheading">value</p>
                <p class="biodata">value</p>
                <p class="bioheading">value</p>
                <p class="biodata">value</p>
```

same for this:

```
<div id="vitalbox" class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p class="bioheading">value</p>
            <p class="biodata">value</p>
            <p class="bioheading">value</p>
            <p class="biodata">value</p>
            <p class="bioheading">value</p>
            <p class="biodata">value</p>
        </div>
```

Here how to get the gender value ? :

```
<input name="Gender" value="m" type="hidden">
```

Especially this html can be malformed.
Sorry for this beginner question.

Best regards.

EDIT:

```
k=0
a_table=[]
bday1=''
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    a_table.append(str(link.get('href')))
    #out.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(p.text)+'\n')
    if re.match(regs4,str(link.get('href')),re.M) != None:
        bday1 = re.search(regs1,str(link.get('href')),re.M)
    else:
        bday1 = 'http://url.com/calendar.asp?calmonth=01&amp;calyear=2018&amp;calday=01'
    k=k+1
```

I try this to collect a href= and check when it is wanted url. with regex
.find_All() will not work get the error:

```
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So I am using .findAll()

This will not work also there is several input:

```
for _input in soup.findAll('input'):
    if str(_input.attrs['name']) == 'Gender':
        if str(_input.attrs['value']) == 'f':
            out.write('F') 
        elif str(_input.attrs['value']) == 'm':
            out.write('M')
        else:
            out.write('—')
```

get this error:

```
builtins.KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: Check this page- [how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe)

Answer (score 3):

Just some modifications/improvements to the Bill's answer:

- you can use `.select_one()` instead of `.select()[0]` to find a single element by a CSS selector
- you don't need `attrs` and use a dictionary-like access to tag attributes:

  ```
  soup.select_one('#headshot img')['src']
  ```
- [`.get_text()` is a bit more robust than accessing `.text` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35496332/771848)
- you can improve the CSS selector used to get the `p` elements and use the fact that class names start with `bio`:

  ```
  #vitalbox #home p[class^=bio]
  ```
- you should be using `find_all()` and not a deprecated `findAll()`
- you can even use `soup('p')` shortcut instead of `soup.find_all('p')` and `soup.input['value']` instead of `soup.find('input').attrs['value']`

Comment: p[class^=bio] this doesn't work for me. Also want to get p[class^=bio] and div[class^=bio].

Answer (score 2):

With `select` `#headshot` finds the element with `id` 'headshot', and `img` find the descendant element with this tag. Since `select` can potentially find a list of elements, we insist on the first item in the list, and ask for that elements `src` attribute.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <div id="headshot">
... <img title="Photo of someone" alt="Photo of somenone" src="url/file.jpg">
... </div>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> soup.select('#headshot img')[0].attrs['src']
'url/file.jpg'
```

Use `findAll` to identify all of the `p` elements, then in a list comprehension, get the text of each.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <div class="biodata">value</div>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata">value</p>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata"><a href"http://url.com/month=01&amp;year=2018&amp;day=02">January 01, 1900</a> (117 years old)</p>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata">value</p>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata">value</p>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> [p.text for p in soup.findAll('p')]
['value', 'value', 'value', 'value', 'January 01, 1900 (117 years old)', 'value', 'value', 'value', 'value']
```

As above, use `select` to unambiguously specify the content required, then  get the text values in a list comprehension.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <div id="vitalbox" class="tab-content">
... <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
... <div class="row">
... <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata">value</p>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
... <p class="biodata">value</p>
... <p class="bioheading">value</p>
...  <p class="biodata">value</p>
...  </div>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> [p.text for p in soup.select('#vitalbox #home .row .col-xs-12 p')]
['value', 'value', 'value', 'value', 'value', 'value']
```

In this case there is only one element, namely `input`; therefore, I use `find`. Since I've used `find` (rather than a method that yields lists) I know at most one element will be returned. I request its attribute.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <input name="Gender" value="m" type="hidden">'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> soup.find('input').attrs['value']
'm'
```