# how i get the image link from source code in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I request url and get the following response.

```
<img src="img/sample.png" /><br />
```

I don't know how to get the image url with python 3

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129908/131187

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the response and extract the url:

```
response = '<img src="img/sample.png" /><br />'
url = 'http://example.com/'

img_url = url + response.split('"')[1]
```

For further informations about .split() visit:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split