# getText() vs text() vs get_text()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a chunk of html extracted with bs4 as following

```
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small" id="productDescription">
<!-- show up to 2 reviews by default -->
<p>Satin Smooth Universal Protective Wax Pot Collars by Satin Smooth</p>
</div>
```

To extract the text I was using text.strip()

```
output.text()
```

It gave me the output `"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"`

While I used `output.get_text()` and `output.getText()`, I got the desired text

What are the differences between these 3?  why the get_text() and getText() is giving the same output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between .text and .get\_text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496332/differences-between-text-and-get-text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are very similar:

- `.get_text` is a function that returns the text of a tag as a string
- `.text` is a property that calls `get_text` (so it's identical, except you don't use parantheses)
- `.getText` is an alias of `get_text`

I would use `.text` whenever possible, and `.get_text(...)` when you need to pass custom arguments (e.g. `foo.get_text(strip=True, seperator='\n')`).

Comment: Thanks! I just found that  printing `output.p.contents` also gives me the text in a list with tabs and new lines.

Comment: Typo: `expect` `->` `except`

Comment: @NChauhan Thanks! Feel free to fix obvious mistakes like that (or suggest the fix, if you don't have enough rep to actually edit)

Comment: I would have, but editing requires at least a 6 character change :)

Answer (score 1):

By my knowledge which is very basic.

`.text` only gives you output in string form while
`getText()` gives you accessibility to apply various custom arguments over the strings you want from the given object