# Getting class name from span tag in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to data scraping and I am using BeautifulSoup to grap some data from a webpage.
I'm trying to get the r100 in the span tag.
I know r100 is the class name, but this data is required. Is it possible?

my code

```
st2=st1.find("span",attrs={"class":"rating"})
print(st2)
```

out

```
<span class="rating r100"></span>
```

Comment: What output are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I only want 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the class then index. It is a multi-valued class with 2 values i.e. 1 at index 0 and the other at index 1.

```
st2['class'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One you have `<span class="rating r100"></span>` in `st2`.
You can use `text`

**Code**
`st2.text`

Also, you can use `get_text()` which will allow you to pass more arguments such as

`(separator, strip, types)`

Comment: When I write, I get it as a printout, unfortunately `st2.get_text()  ` out `..`

Comment: Try text instead. And look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496332/differences-between-text-and-get-text